# WP Admin default view mode for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, wp-admin, views

To change it globally to `excerpt` for every post type I can use:

```
function my_default_posts_list_mode( $default ) {
  return 'excerpt';
}
add_filter( 'default-posts-list-mode', 'my_default_posts_list_mode' );
```

But how can I achieve the same only for a Custom Post Type?

**Explanation:**

I've created a Custom Post Type. In WP Admin the default view mode is set to list (edit.php?post_type=my_post_type&mode=list). I want it to be `excerpt`, but **only** for my Custom Post Type not affecting other post types.

I can do this manually by adding `&mode=excerpt` to the URL like so: `edit.php?post_type=my_post_type&mode=excerpt`, however I want this to be done automatically.

Comment: Can you expand more on the problem you are having? Thanks.

Comment: @iambriansreed I've updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the mode URL variable but in the load try this:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_default_posts_list_mode' );
function my_default_posts_list_mode() {

    $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
    if ( $post_type && $post_type == 'my_post_type' && !isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] ) )
        $_REQUEST['mode'] = 'excerpt';
}
```

Got the "insipration" from here: [Set Default Listing "View" in Admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/set-default-listing-view-in-admin)

Comment: Thanks, but where I can set my CPT name?

Comment: Sorry, just added it now. Check it out.

Comment: There are two buttons under "Search" in posts listing: List View and Excerpt View. I can't switch back to List View. And your code affects all post types ;/

Comment: Ok. Should be good now. Change my_post_type to the necessary post type.

Comment: I've change my_post_type in your updated code but it's still affecting all post types and I can't switch back to list view in my custom post type. It's weird - I'm dealing with it about 3 days ;s

Comment: Yes first issue done. I can now switch to list view in my custom post type. However it is still affecting other post types like default Post.

Comment: Remove your `add_filter( 'default-posts-list-mode'` code.

Comment: I removed it yesterday. Everything is fine now, but your code still affects all post types. If I click my CPT name in the WP Menu on the left it shows correctly with mode=excerpt (and I can switch back to list view) and then when I click "Posts" it shows default posts with mode=excerpt too ;/

Comment: Yes!!! Finaly!!! I got it working with your help! Thanks! But in your answer your wrote: `take into account post types that support excerpts`. What part of your code do this?

Comment: I just removed that comment. It was necessary when you didn't exactly specify the post type.

Comment: @SLH Did this answer your question? If so don't forget to mark it as the accepted correct answer!